# Token re-generation error in wso2 store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I can't re-generate the access-token of the application in WSO2-store. So i can't access my APIs in store. I attached the screenshot with this. Can anybody help me on this to solve?

[image]

Comment: Please post backend error logs

Comment: Can you post logs from <APIM>/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log?